# Does Smart/Dumb Component Architecture create some complexity in some aspect of angular application

Tags: javascript, angular

(Please refer below image which reading)

Having issue with correctly identifies what would be smart component (container) what would be dumb component (presentation) in my sample layout. If I explain my scenario I have tab container, let assume have two tabs X and Y. At **first level having container component** which hold individual tab basically it is landing component for any tab. In a case with specific tab ex: X having layout or container component which arrange all primitive components those belongs to tabs X.

Having some confusion correctly identify which should be smart component in this scenario. My initial though was it would be **Container hold tabs components (outer most component)**. But having discussion with team and with some arguments decided to it would be **Container Layout Components of X Tabs**. Then my thought was for each tab we should have a smart component.

In out discussion below list of arguments came out with against outer most component as smart component.

1. Having outer most container as smart component it is required for
   few    level of Input/Output  bindings.
2. Having outer most container as smart component if in case it need to remove tabs X all associate services are located in some where else need to be remove and some time those would be miss.
3. It would be violation of Single Responsible Principle

So then I was get bit of confusion since all those arguments having some validity so in those scenario what should be consider when deciding smart component? I think if we decided those factor there would be having more smart components in the application but as I read out the application should have few number of smart component.

[image]